# Появляется горизонтальный скролл в bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Подскажите, в чем проблема?
В тот момент, когда я создаю 5 блоков в 'section' в 'div.row'
возникает горизонтальный скролл, так и не понял откуда он берется....
Происходит это здесь...https://starteducation.space/

```css
/* SECTION 1 */

.reasons h2 {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.reasons .col-2 {
  background: #fff;
  height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="content reasons">
  <h2>Пять веских причин вступить в наш клуб</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2 offset-3">
      <p>Test 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 offset-2">
      <p>Test 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="w-100"></div>
    <div class="col-2 offset-2">
      <p>Test 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 offset-1">
      <p>Test 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 offset-1">
      <p>Test 5</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все дело в том, что у вас блок `.row` находится вне какого-либо блока-контейнера. Используйте `.container-fluid` для блока с нефиксированной шириной или `.container` для блока с фиксированной.

Особенность сетки Bootstrap в том, что у блоков `.row` есть отрицательный `margin` слева и справа, что и вызывает появление горизонтальной прокрутки, если блок `.row` находится вне блока с `padding`, компенсирующим этот отступ.

```css
/* SECTION 1 */

.reasons h2 {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.reasons .col-2 {
  background: #fff;
  height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="content reasons container-fluid">
  <h2>Пять веских причин вступить в наш клуб</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2 offset-3">
      <p>Test 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 offset-2">
      <p>Test 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="w-100"></div>
    <div class="col-2 offset-2">
      <p>Test 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 offset-1">
      <p>Test 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 offset-1">
      <p>Test 5</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Да да, из за невнимательности читал 'content' как 'container' и никак не мог увидеть....спасибо!